# RESTEasy returns http code 200 for requests which don't fulfill @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy, java-ee-8

I use WildFly 16 and am doing some experiment on Java EE 8 Security API. I have a JAX-RS endpoint like this (with some definition in web.xml, jboss-web.xml):

```java
@Path("/secured")
public class SecuredResource {

    @Inject
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @GET
    @Path("/greet")
    @RolesAllowed({"USER"})
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response greet() {
        return Response.ok().entity("Hello " + securityContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName()).build();
    }
}
```

As I expected, requests which don't have the "USER" role don't reach the code there but those requests get http responses with the code 200. I want to return "401 Unauthorized" for those requests, not 200.

[According to some document of RESTEasy](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html), it's supposed to behave like that:

> How does Resteasy do authorization? Well, its really simple. It just sees if a method is annotated with @RolesAllowed and then just does HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole. If one of the @RolesAllowed passes, then allow the request, otherwise, a response is sent back with a 401 (Unauthorized) response code.

But it's not like that in my case. How can I make it work that way?

[This is the whole project of my experimental implementation](https://github.com/nuzayats/ee8security/tree/use_role). It also has [a test case which shows my expectation](https://github.com/nuzayats/ee8security/blob/dc87979f3336377a1ae9e25d06a4e6ba38dcaa08/src/test/java/ee8security/GreetIT.java#L21-L29). It can run with `./mvnw clean verify`

Comment: Did you 1) configure the required `context-param`? 2) configure the required `security-contraints` and `security-roles`? These are _both_required according to the docs you linked to.

Comment: Yes https://github.com/nuzayats/ee8security/blob/use_role/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: Look at the complete example web.xml from your link. It has a `<login-conf>`. I believe this is what's actually sets up the _authentication_. It says to use Basic Authentication and also declares the realm to use. You will have to configure the realm with your server.

Comment: I knew that, but in my understanding, in Java EE 8 Security API, realms are not mandatory and roles are [handled here with HttpAuthenticationMechanism](https://github.com/nuzayats/ee8security/blob/use_role/src/main/java/ee8security/JwtHttpAuthenticationMechanism.java). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm just going off what the docs you linked to says. It does mention there are some quirks with their approach. Not sure what those quirks are.